# Rails: Is there a rails trick to adding commas to large numbers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to have rails print out a number with commas in it?

For example, if I have a number 54000000.34, I can run <%= number.function %>, which would print out "54,000,000.34"

thanks!

Answer (score 395, accepted):

You want the [`number_with_delimiter`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#M001971) method. For example:

```
<%= number_with_delimiter(@number, :delimiter => ',') %>
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`number_with_precision`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#M001972) method to ensure that the number is always displayed with two decimal places of precision:

```
<%= number_with_precision(@number, :precision => 2, :delimiter => ',') %>
```

Comment: Can this be used in a helper i.e module? or is it just for views? 

is there a equivalent method for a moudle? 

thanks

Comment: @Mo It's a view helper method. You should be able to use it from a module by including `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` within the module.

Comment: I believe by default the delimiter is a comma so you wouldn't need to pass in that option in this case.

Comment: You should leave the delimiter off so that the current locale can decide what to use. This allows locales that use periods for delimiters to be displayed properly rather than putting what they would consider a decimal point between thousands. See coloradoblue answer below.

Comment: Rails 4 syntax: <%= number_with_precision(@number, precision: 0, delimiter: ',') %>

Comment: I think you mean ruby 1.9, not rails 4, @meetalexjohnson

Comment: Beware: `number_with_delimiter` is overly-complex and really slow, with enormous depths of call stacks. It uses `i18n` to be able to format any numbers known to humanity and extraterrestrial civilizations (or maybe just to choose either `,` or `.` for decimal digits, even if you specify it as argument). It allocates thousands of objects (so its performance patterns are complex and hard to profile). Consider just using regexps if you don't need to support different ways to format numbers depending on locale.

Comment: @kolen I must agree. We were getting some performance hits and methods from the NumberHelper were the root cause.

Comment: `number_with_precision` was perfect for my use. Thank you!

Comment: seconding the call to beware `number_with_delimiter`'s performance -- I was using it in a large financial report and it ate up at least two-thirds of the rendering time.

Answer (score 153):

For anyone not using rails:

```
number.to_s.reverse.gsub(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/, '\\1,').reverse
```

Comment: Nice. And your answer seems to be *minutely* (only a fraction of a second over one million iterations) faster than the approach presented [here](http://www.rubyquiz.com/quiz113.html): `number.to_s.reverse.scan(/(?:\d*\.)?\d{1,3}-?/).join(',').reverse`

Comment: can you explain what is going on here?
number.to_s.reverse.gsub(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/, '\\1,').reverse

Comment: Sure, it reverses the string, then adds a comma after any sequence of 3 digits that is also followed by another digit, then reverses it back.

Comment: @pguardiario - I just tried it in irb.  2051851.1542541 turns into 2,051,851.1,542,541

Comment: @renosis - I see what you mean now, this is for formatting currency. So 2 decimals, not 7.

Comment: @pguardiario - it is not like it is a big deal, I still used it in my code. All I did was only apply it to the whole number part.

Comment: @pguardiario What's the extra \ for in the \\1? isn't `\1` sufficient? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `\1` is sufficient

Comment: the double reverse is not necessary. you can do something like what fxfilmxf did in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18884577/2544629).

Comment: @renosis With decimals it becomes `number.to_s.reverse.gsub(/(\d+\.)?(\d{3})(?=\d)/, '\\1\\2,').reverse`

Comment: @renosis or you could use a dedicated library, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41431659/6320039)

Answer (score 67):

The direct way to do this, [with or without Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#how-to-load-core-extensions), is:

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions'

123456.to_fs(:delimited)     # => "123,456"
123456.789.to_fs(:delimited) # => "123,456.789"
```

For more options, see [Active Support Core Extensions - Numeric - Formatting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#formatting).

Comment: And with this inclusion you can use `ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_delimited` as well. This answer deserve a lot more upvotes.

Comment: I'm getting uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Autoload (NameError) 

Comment: @CruzNunez If it's not already loaded, you'll need to [`require "active_support"`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#how-to-load-core-extensions) first. I've updated the answer.

Comment: You make the assumption that `active_support` is installed, which would be the case for the OP. Careful not to assume it should be done this way for all Ruby non-Rails code.

Comment: you can also hav a custom delimiter and separator

```ruby
12345678901.234.to_s(:delimited, delimiter: " ", separator: ":")
=> "12 345 678 901:234"
```

Comment: I guess this changed in some version, but it seems like this should be .to_fs(:delimited) now.

Comment: I've been using Rails for 15 years and never knew about `.to_fs( :delimited )`. So cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 33):

If you want to add commas outside of views and you don't want to include some modules, you can use [number_to_delimited](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/NumberHelper/number_to_delimited) method (rails version >= 4.02). For example:

```
#inside anywhere
ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_delimited(1000000) # => "1,000,000"
```

Answer (score 32):

Yes, use the [NumberHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#M001971). The method you are looking for is [number_with_delimiter](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#M001971).

```
 number_with_delimiter(98765432.98, :delimiter => ",", :separator => ".")
 # => 98,765,432.98
```

Answer (score 21):

If you're doing it a lot but also FYI because it's not implied by the above, Rails has sensible defaults for the `number_with_delimiter` method.

```
#inside controller or view
number_with_delimiter(2444323.4)
#=> 2,444,323.30

#inside console
helper.number_with_delimiter(233423)
#=> 233,423
```

No need to supply the delimiter value if you're doing it the most typical way.

Comment: This has the added benefit of using the current locale. This is really important in international apps since some locales use comma for decimal and period for thousands separator.

Answer (score 19):

A better way for those not using rails that handles decimals:

```
parts = number.to_s.split('.')
parts[0].gsub!(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/, "\\1,")
parts.join('.')
```

If you want a different delimiter, change the last ',' in the regex.

For bonus, this is how the regex is working:

- gsub replaces everything that matches the regex with the second parameter passed to gsub. In this case that is `\\1`. `\\1` becomes `\1` when evaluated which matches the first capture group in the regex. In this regex that is `(\d)`.
- `(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+)` is matching a digit followed by 1 or more groups of 3 digits. The first set of parens is our `\1` capture group, the second would be `\2`. If we were just to leave it at that we would get:
  `123456.gsub!(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+)/, "\\1,") #=> 1,2,3,456` This is because 1234 matches, 2345 matches and 3456 matches so we put a comma after the 1, the 2, and the 3.
- By adding the (?!\d) we are matching anything that comes before that doesn't precede a digit so `(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))` means match a digit followed by 3 digits that is not followed by a digit. The reason why this works is that gsub will keep replacing things that match the string. If we were only going to replace the first match then for a number like 123456789 we would get 123456,789. Since 123456,789 still matches our regex we get 123,456,789.

Here is where I got the code: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/number_helper.rb#L298-L300

And here is where I learned about what is going on in that regex: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm

Comment: works like a charm, especially in Liquid template lang: `{{ value | round | replace: "(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))", "$1," | prepend: "$" }}`

Answer (score 2):

new syntax

```
number_with_delimiter(@number, delimiter: ",")
```

If you you want to user delimeter for money then you can do

```
number_to_currency(@number)
```

this will add `$` too. If you are using `money` gem then you can do

```
Money.new(@number,"USD").format
```

This will also put `$`.

[number_with_delimiter](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_with_delimiter)

[ruby money](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money)

[number_to_currency](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html)

Answer (score 2):

I had this challenge when working on a **Rails 6** application.

If the number is for the **price** of an item or has to do with **currency**, then you can use `number_to_currency` **ActionView Helper**

**Here's how to do it**:

```
number_to_currency("123456789")                      # => $123456789
number_to_currency(1234567890.50)                    # => $1,234,567,890.50
number_to_currency(1234567890.506)                   # => $1,234,567,890.51
number_to_currency(1234567890.506, precision: 3)     # => $1,234,567,890.506
number_to_currency(1234567890.506, locale: :fr)      # => 1 234 567 890,51 â‚¬
number_to_currency(1234567890.50, unit: '₦', delimiter: ',', precision: 0)    # => ₦1,234,567,890
number_to_currency(1234567890.50, unit: "R$", separator: ",", delimiter: "")  # => R$1234567890,50
```

You can read up more about it here in the Rails documentation: [number_to_currency](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_currency)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 2):

**For Ruby guys:**
Formatting numbers (integers only) with a comma separator between every group of thousands.

```
number = 12345678
numStr1 = number.to_s.reverse.scan(/.{1,3}/).join(',').reverse
puts numStr1             # => 12,345,678

numStr2 = number.to_s.gsub(/\B(?=(...)*\b)/, ',')
puts numStr2             # => 12,345,678
```

Comment: The `number.to_s.reverse.scan(/.{1,3}/)` piece seems like a good place to start if you wanted to produce output like 4.32M or 12.3G.  The top two array entries could be joined with "." and then trimmed to the length you want, reverse, and add the suffix based upon the length of the array `scan` produced.

Answer (score 1):

You can use methods from `ActiveSupport`

For example:

`ActiveSupport::NumberHelper::number_to_currency(10000.1234,{precision: 2,unit: ''})`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that does not use Helpers: format with 2 decimal places, and then replace . by ,

```
puts(("%.2f" % 2.5666).gsub('.',','))
>> 2,57
```

Comment: I believe the question was about commas for [digit grouping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Digit_grouping), not comma as intergral part/fraction part decimal separator that your answer achieves.  (as that wiki link explains, due to the long-standing confusion, internetional standards now recommend spaces only for digit grouping)

Answer (score 1):

```
  def add_commas(numstring)
    correct_idxs = (1..100).to_a.select{|n| n % 6 == 0}.map{|n| n - 1}
     numstring.reverse.chars.join(",").chars.select.with_index{|x, i| i.even? || correct_idxs.include?(i)}.join.reverse
  end
```

This was my way in ruby

Addition edit: 
Basically it adds all commas in between the numbers and only selects the ones where the index + 1 % 6

I figured the commas up to 100 was fine but if you want a super long number just make 100 a higher number

Answer (score 1):

The following do the trick for both delimiter and precision ([API ref](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.0.0/ActiveSupport%2FNumberHelper:number_to_rounded)).

```
ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_rounded(1234.532, delimiter: ',', precision: 1)
```

(or from views just `number_to_rounded`, no need for the prefix)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

**For Ruby Folks:** functions can be created to set comma to large number integer.

```
def number_with_comma(numStr)
   return numStr.to_s.gsub(/\B(?=(...)*\b)/, ',')
end
a = number_with_comma 1234567
puts a   => 1,234,567

x = 9876543
y = number_with_comma x
puts y   => 9,876,543
```

Answer (score -1):

for javascript folks

```
function numberWithDelimiter(value) {
    return (value+"").split("").reverse().join("").replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, '$1,').split("").reverse().join("")
}
```

:)