# inserting commas to separate large number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

HI

Is there a way i can add commas to a number like so:

```
num= 1234567
```

then becomes

```
num = 1,234,567
```

I would like to make this call in my helper i.e module

thanks

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078347/is-there-a-rails-trick-to-adding-commas-to-large-numbers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [number_with_delimiter](http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#M000369).

From your helpers:

```
number_with_delimiter(12345678)       # => 12,345,678
```

**UPDATE:** The [code](http://gist.github.com/484764) for the method.

Comment: Yes, But you could include the module, or, if you don't want(like) to include views helpers outside, here's the code for the `number_with_delimeter` method http://gist.github.com/484764

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this outside of a view? It's purely visual, and provides no extra information about the value itself.

Comment: @jdl, I would use this helper outside the views in following situations: logging, tracing, flash messages etc. etc.

Comment: +1 for cribbing the code for number_with_delimiter so that you don't have to include all of the view helpers.

Comment: @KandadaBoggu Ah, gotcha. I would call all of those "views" but I can see that in the context of a Rails app you'd still need to require explicit access to the helper outside of the official "view".

Comment: +1 for including the code, so that I can port this to a ruby script.  thanks