# Does Ruby have any number formatting classes?

Tags: ruby

Does Ruby have any Formatter classes or methods that can be used to format numbers for things like currency, etc., or are there any gems that do this, or do you have to write you own?

Comment: Any chance you could provide us whit examples? The question is pretty wide.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Ruby has all the standard print formatters, available either via printf, sprintf or using `'formatstring' % [var1, ...]`.

```
>> '%.2f' % 3.14159 #=> "3.14"
>> '%4s %-4s' % ['foo', 'bar'] #=> " foo bar "
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
1234567890.123.to_s.reverse.gsub(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/, '\\1,').reverse
=> "1,234,567,890.123"
```

Taken from a comment by @pguardiario in a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078347/is-there-a-rails-trick-to-adding-commas-to-large-numbers)

Comment: A little broken. `1234567890.1234.to_s.reverse.gsub(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/, '\\1,').reverse
=> "1,234,567,890.1,234"`

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Kernel#sprintf` (or `Kernel#format`) and do it that way. [API Link](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005962).

Answer (score 3):

Ruby provides `Kernel#format` class method that looks more like the python 3.x method. Checkout [Ruby's Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format) for more details.
This can be used to format both string and number.There are others like `%e` and `%g` for exponential and etc.

Below are some examples.

*number*
use `%f` for *float* and `%d` for *integer*

```
format('%.2f', 2.0)     # => "2.00"
format('%.d', 2.0)      # => "2"
```

*string* use `%s`

```
format('%.4s', "hello") # => "hell"
format('%6s', "hello")  # => " hello"
format('%-6s', "hello") # => "hello "
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [`ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html) in Rails' ActionView gem.