# rails decimal scale => 2 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a product column like so:

```
t.decimal :price, :precision => 12, :scale => 2
```

and it keeps returning 500.0 instead of the expected two decimal 500.00. Then I tried manually changing the product price via the console and it'll only save 1 decimal place.

```
>product.price = 500.00
=> 500.0
>product.price
=> #<BigDecimal:7ff479c6ba40,'0.5E3',9(36)>
```

How do I get the decimal column to save and return two decimal places?

Comment: What happens if you don't use an integer value, but something like `1.234`?

Comment: @amiuhle it goes  => 1.234, => #<BigDecimal:7f871104d540,'0.1234E1',18(36)>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scale` specifies number of digits after the decimal point preserved in the database. Saving `1.234` will round to `1.23`, `500.00` will be stored as `500.00`.

In Ruby on Rails, they will be represented as a `BigDecimal`. The `BigDecimal` will not know about the format that was used in the DB. If its value is `500.0`, its `to_s` method will output it as `500.0` because that's accurate enough.

To format the values as currency, use the [`number_to_currency`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency) helper method.

Also see [Ruby on Rails: best method of handling currency / money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019939/ruby-on-rails-best-method-of-handling-currency-money) and [Does Ruby have any number formatting classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175326/does-ruby-have-any-number-formatting-classes)

Comment: so is there no way to force the db to return 2 decimals without using a view helper?

Comment: but that's not what's happening with my db, 1.234 is being saved as 1.234, and product.price.to_s => "1.234". So the value's not being rounded up even though scale is defined in the schema.

Comment: It will only get truncated when it's saved to the db and then restored. Why don't you want to use a view helper?

Comment: Because the values are being sent to another app via an Api. With over 200 currency values over 6 models it'll save a lot of programming time. It's a bit weird really, I was under the impression that scale limits db entries to 2 decimals and returns 2 decimals...apparently not.

Comment: It does limit. If you `save` and then `reload` a model, it will truncate `1.234` to `1.23`.

Comment: you're right. It does limit the entry to two decimals. Seems that I'm stuck with one  decimal for .00 though.  Thanks!