# Ruby equivalent of Python's conventional number separation

Tags: ruby

In Python, we have something like `print(f'{int(input()):,}')` that separates numbers by commas. That is for example, if we provide the input of `70671891032` we get `70,671,891,032`. Is there anything similar to this in Ruby (without the use of `regex`)?

Comment: In Rails / active support, there is a method `number_with_delimiter` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1078366/2981429) but I'm not sure there's one in plain Ruby.

Comment: If you're not using Rails you can load the method from the `activesupport` gem: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_delimited ... this gem contains a ton of useful core extensions

Comment: ActiveSupport uses regex, so, I could infere that Ruby doesn't have what you are looking for. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activesupport/lib/active_support/number_helper/number_to_delimited_converter.rb

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's built-in [string formatting](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) doesn't have an option for a thousands separator.

If you don't want to use regular expressions, you could [`insert`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#insert-method) a separator every 3 characters from the right, e.g. via [`step`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Numeric.html#step-method):

```
input = 70671891032

string = input.to_s

(string.size - 3).step(1, -3) do |i|
  string.insert(i, ',')
end

string
#=> "70,671,891,032"
```

Comment: Does this really make sense? After all, the separator depends on the locale and is not necessarily a `,`. This point is also a bit unclear from the OPs question: Does he **always** wants to use a comma, or did he give this just as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I expect this is not what you were looking for, but it does convert a non-negative integer to a string of digits with thousands separators.

```
def commafy(n)
  s = ''
  loop do
    break s if n.zero? 
    n, n3 = n.divmod(1000)   
    s[0,0] = (n.zero? ? ("%d" % n3) : (",%03d" % n3)) 
  end
end
```

```
input = 70671891032
```

```
commafy(input)
  #=> "70,671,891,032"
```